# Why don't more languages use an immutable model like Clojures?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, immutability

Most of my understanding of how clojure handles immutables comes from [this](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1). This seems really clever to me; it makes things like copying and changing one value or adding a new value to the end of a collection nearly as quick as it would be for a mutable object. However, from what I understand many (if not most) other languages that rely heavily on immutables don't use this sort of structure (Haskell, Scala, etc.). Why is that? is there some disadvantage to such a tree structure that I'm missing, or just a relatively recent idea?

Comment: A good question, but I hesitate to upvote because I'm not sure whether it's on topic.

Comment: I've wanted this in Python.  It would probably radically change the way I write code in Python.

Comment: Could you consider adding something to this question to make it easier to tell if an answer is "correct", for what you are asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is your understanding is mistaken.  The kind of data structure you are referring to is called *persistent*, and nearly all functional programming languages have made heavy use of them for at least a couple decades now, including Scala and Haskell.

Where they are still not heavily used is in primarily imperative languages that also do functional programming as an afterthought.  That's why trying to "go immutable" in these languages is often much less efficient than in primarily functional languages.

Comment: So this is good to know, but persistent is a really general word. how could I look more into those data structures?

Comment: Googling "persistent data structures" gives good results.  Chris Okasaki wrote the canonical book on the subject.

Comment: "functional as an afterthought" `<--` That's a great phrase to describe a lot of languages that make claims about being such.